# OnGui elements interacting with other OnGui elements

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, kinect

Within my 2d game i wsih to have a number of OnGui elements there for the user to select, however, the cursor that im using is another ongui element(using kinect to navigate) is this possible by any chance, at the moment im using planes but i will be zooming in and out of the camera so ill essentially need them attatched to the screen. Any ideas, suggestions or workarounds.
THis is currently my cursor.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;

public class PillarAgent : MonoBehaviour {

public SkeletonWrapper sw;
public Vector3 distance;

public float progress =0f;

public Texture2D cursor;
public Texture2D load;

public Camera mainCam;

public float startTime;
private int roundedRestSecounds;

// Use this for initialization

    float differencex = 0;
    float differencey = 0;

void Start () {

    distance =new Vector3(0f,0f,0f);

}
float translate(float value, float leftMin, float leftMax, 
        float rightMin,float rightMax)
{
    float leftSpan = leftMax - leftMin;
    float rightSpan= rightMax - rightMin;

    float valueScaled = (value-leftMin)/(leftSpan);
    return rightMin+(valueScaled * rightSpan);
}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (sw.pollSkeleton())
    {
        distance.x=sw.bonePos[0,0].x - sw.bonePos[0,7].x;//5 is left shoulder
        distance.y=sw.bonePos[0,0].y -sw.bonePos[0,7].y;


        differencex=translate(distance.x,.6f,0,0,Screen.width);
        differencey=translate(distance.y,-.5f,0,0,Screen.height);
        //Debug.Log();

        float width = sw.bonePos[0,5].x+ sw.bonePos[0,9].x;
        float height =sw.bonePos[0,4].y- sw.bonePos[0,0].y;
        float heightdiv= (height/2)+sw.bonePos[0,0].y;        
    }    
}

void OnGUI() {
    //left top width height
    Rect r = new Rect(differencex,differencey,80,50);

    GUI.Label(r,cursor);
    GUI.BeginGroup(new Rect(differencex,differencey+50,50*Mathf.Clamp01(progress),15));
    //Debug.Log(progress);
    GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(0,0,50,50),load);
    GUI.EndGroup();

    transform.position =mainCam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(differencex,Screen.height-differencey,50));

    //mainCam.fieldOfView()    
}

void OnCollisionStay(Collision Other)
{
    startTime+=Time.deltaTime;

    if(Other.gameObject.GetComponent(typeof(TextControl)))
    {
        roundedRestSecounds=Mathf.CeilToInt(Time.time);

        progress = Time.time *0.2f;

        CurrentState=true;
    }
    else if(Other.gameObject.tag==("Scalpal")){


        progress = startTime *0.5f;
        //scallpall activated
        //    
    }        
}

void OnCollisionExit(Collision Other){
    startTime =0f;
    progress =0f;        
}

public Boolean CurrentState{get;set;}
}
```

The next class is essentially the class in which i pick up my tools, currently this code doesnt work(not sure why), but what i wish to do is select  some tools which show up on the screen so that i can use them,for e.g pick up paint brush start painting bricks or what not. at the moment i have my tools on a plane, i wish to always have them on the screen at all times when the camera moves.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SelectTool : MonoBehaviour {

public Tools tools;
public float startTime;
public bool ScalpalSelected;
public GameObject selectedTool;

void Start()
{
    tools = this.GetComponent<Tools>(); //in order to use this tools muyst be attached to the game object
    //this is essentially saying  with regards to this game object get the component named tools
}
void update()
{

}
void OnCollisionStay(Collision Other)
{
    startTime +=Time.deltaTime;

    if(startTime >5f){
        if(Other.collider.tag==("Scalpal"))
        {
            selectedTool = Other.collider.gameObject;
            Debug.Log(selectedTool+" What in gods good name is:" +tools.utilities[0]);

        }
        else {
            selectedTool=null;
        }
        if(selectedTool){
            for(int i=0;i<tools.utilities.Length;i++)
            {

            }    
        }


            ScalpalSelected=true;
            renderer.material.color = Color.yellow;    
    }
}
void OncollisionStay(Collision other){

    startTime = 0f;
}

}
```

Comment: Hello.  It is difficult to understand exactly what you are trying to do.  Please try to expand on your questions, giving examples of code you are having trouble with.

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey sorry about that, essentially the only way i can think of achieving this is to do what i have done with the cursor, and that is to create another object to interact with the game world.

Comment: well, if I understood what you said correctly, you want your plane objects to move together with the camera. An easy way to do this is to stick those Plane Objects into the camera as child objects. Then when you move the camera, they'll automatically move with it

Comment: thank you @StevenMills Do you have any example of how this can be done?

Comment: within unity, while looking at the Hierarchy window, simply drag and drop the planes onto the main camera. You should then see a small arrow symbol next to the camera, which opens a list of all child objects within it. If you're still unsure, try looking on youtube, there should be a video somewhere showing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comment section to the question I will assume that you want to know how to do this:

> "... you want your plane objects to move together with the camera ..." - Steven Mills
>
> "thank you @StevenMills Do you have any example of how this can be done?" j bel

While the answer provided in the comments is to just *manually add the planes as children of the camera* (a very straightforward, manual approach), I will give another way to do this through scripting (in light of maybe this will help someone else out disregarding the likeliness of someone using this solution).

The idea of this is to create a script (thus following being attached to the `MainCamera`) that will search through all of the `GameObject` in the `Object Hierarchy` with the method [GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html). Once we have all our `GameObject` with the associated `Tag`, we can then loop through the array and parent the attached script's `GameObject` to each.

```
public class ParentGameObjects : MonoBehaviour {
    //The tag to search for on all game objects in the hierarchy
    public String objectTag;
    
    //The game objects that we will parent the main camera to
    private GameObject[] children;
    //It's not necessary to store references to the children but if you want to modify them at some point you will be able to
    
    void Start() {
        //Find all game objects with the tag we want
        children = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(objectTag);
        //Loop through all of the game objects found and parent this object's transform
        for(int i = 0; i < children.Length; i++) {
            children[i].transform.parent = transform;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, there are a few things you have to do for this script to work:

1. Attach this script to any `GameObject` that you want to parent other objects to.
2. In the `Inspector` of the `GameObject` that the script is attached to, enter in the name of the `Tag` you want to use.
3. For all `GameObject`(s) in the `Hierarchy` that should be added as children, assign the same `Tag`.

Of course there are other things you can do like, for example, instead of only searching for one `Tag` be able to search for multiple but that requires a bit (not exactly much) more work. Nonetheless, I hope this will at least be useful information to someone on how parenting works via scripting.